# User Plugin in Artifactory not loading

Tags: artifactory

I have Artifactory 6.20.1 running in a Docker container. I'm trying to install the artifactCleanup plugin (https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup)

I have put the artifactCleanup.groovy file in the corresponding folder:

```
$ ls -all /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/plugins/
total 36 
drwxr-xr-x 2 artifact artifact  4096 Feb 24 10:28 . 
drwxr-xr-x 3 artifact artifact  4096 Feb 23 15:24 .. 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 artifact artifact  5829 Feb 23 15:25 README.md 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 artifact artifact 14043 Feb 23 15:26 artifactCleanup.groovy 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 artifact artifact   325 Feb 24 10:28 artifactCleanup.json
```

However if I'm trying to see my loaded plugins I get an empty response

```
curl -X GET -u "admin:password" http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/plugins
{}
```

The Server has been restarted before running that request. All commands have been running inside the Docker container. I have been looking at the documentation (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Plugins) on how to install plugins. My User account which was used for the rest calls is an admin account.

Now I am out of clues, why that plugin is not loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I created a wrong directory. Correct directory is

```
/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/plugins
```

which already existed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below reload plugins using the Reload Plugins REST API endpoint.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ReloadPlugins

Please comment here if you are running into any issues.